# Optimize delta table with small file compaction Error in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I'm attempting to create a Synapse table in delta-lake with spark . Source files are small files in json format and often contain frequent updates about the same item . So I planned the table to keep the most latest update about the item .

To Optimize the deltatable I'm using the following command before appending the new records to existing table .

```
spark.sql("SET spark.databricks.delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true")
```

But I still get a notification . I'm sure that this means the autooptimize is not working . How do I proceed to set the autooptimize flag ?

Thanks for the help .

[image]

Comment: How you keeping only the latest update? Provide more information regarding that.

Comment: Hi,

I create a data frame that contains all the updates ( json files ) for  a particular unique device identifier and use the timestamp to retain the most updated record